# Stream closed when trying to upload an IFormFile to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to let the user upload a file to azure. Uploading from the angular based pages to .net core works fine. It comes in as an IFormFile. But when I try to upload the IFormFile to an Azure Blobs Container it throws the following error:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sheet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sheet>(Request.Form["data"]);
IFormFile formFile = Request.Form.Files[0];
data.DateAdded = DateTime.Now.ToString();

if (formFile.FileName.EndsWith(".pdf"))
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        //db.Sheets.Add(data);
        //db.SaveChanges();

        string path = data.StoreLocation.ProjectName;

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(path);
        await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(formFile.OpenReadStream());
    }
}
```

I think the IFormFile upload stream gets closed before the user has uploaded it completly. According to multiple documents this code should work just fine... I did get it to work by saving the file to the filesystem first. But that adds unnecessary actions...

Comment: Why not read it into a `MemoryStream` and upload it from there?

Comment: Thank you, the MemoryStream works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything obviously wrong with your code here. An `ObjectDisposedException` however implies that the object backing the stream has been disposed, which should not occur until the response is returned, which also should not occur as long as you are awaiting the async task like you're doing.

Given that there's not a whole lot to work with here, this is mostly just a guess. What I think is happening is that the request is being cancelled by the client, which should cause a `TaskCancelledException` to be thrown. However, since you're not passing a cancellation token into your async task, there's no way for it to monitor for task cancellation. It's therefore likely choking instead. If the method allows you to pass a cancellation token, you should:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(..., CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ...

    await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(formFile.OpenReadStream(), cancellationToken);
}
```